# Birkhoff's completeness theorem

Tags: logic, proof-theory, universal-algebra

I have two simple questions.

A) Does Birkhoff's completeness theorem follow directly from Gödel's completeness theorem?

B) Is Birkhoff's completeness theorem constructive in the following sense: Given a semantic proof in universal algebra, can we explicitly construct a syntactic proof out of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A) A completeness theorem for a logic says that $T\models \phi$ if and only if $T\vdash \phi$, that is, every model of $T$ satifies $\phi$ if and only if there is a proof of $\phi$ from $T$. To make sense of this statement, we have to fix a proof system for our logic - completeness theorems are about logics together with notions of syntactic consequence.

Gödel's completeness theorem says that first-order logic with a standard proof system is complete, and Birkhoff's completeness theorem says equational logic with a standard proof system is complete. Now, equational logic sits naturally inside first-order logic, so Gödel's completeness theorem tells us that if there's an equation $\phi$ which is (semantically) implied by some equational axioms $T$, then there's a *first-order* proof of $\phi$ from $T$. For all we know, this first-order proof might meander far outside the bounds of equational logic.

Birkhoff's completeness theorem strengthens this by saying that a proof can be found in our equational proof system.

B) I don't know for sure, but I would be very surprised if the answer was yes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure about "For all we know, this first-order proof might meander far outside the bounds of equational logic." - could you add an example? What is precisely the difference between equational logic and first-order logic when applied to, for example, ring theory?

Comment: A first-order proof is a sequence of first-order formulas, each of which follows from the previous by a valid proof rule. In our situation, the assumptions and conclusions are equations, but the intermediate steps of the first-order proof might involve arbitrary first-order formulas, i.e. with negation, disjunction, existential quantifiers, etc. which are not part of equational logic.

Comment: Equational logic is restricted to statements of the form $t_1(\overline{x}) = t_2(\overline{y})$, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms. In first-order you can express that a ring is a field, for example, but you can't do it with an equation.

Comment: It is not really possible to give a good example of a proof of an equation that uses first-order logic: after all, Birkhoff's theorem implies that any use of first-order logic can be eliminated. Of course, this only makes sense in a setting where all the axioms are equations.